# Threejs shadows stopped working and I can't find why

Tags: three.js, shadow

I'm creating a HTML5 game. I'm using Threejs library for 3D graphic. I had shadows working but some time ago it stopped to work. I thought that it was because of the graphic driver and didn't look closer into it at that time. I just turned off shadows. But today I found out that it is not problem with my graphic driver (on my friends laptop there is even other error then on my system).

Here is my code:

```
var Three = new function () {
    var ruinModel,
        towerModel,
        flagModel,
        castleModel_1,
        castleModel_2,
        castleModel_3,
        castleModel_4,
        armyModel,
        mountainModel,
        hillModel,
        treeModel,
        waterModel,
        scene = new THREE.Scene(),
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000),
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true}),
        pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xdddddd),
        theLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1),
        loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(),
        circles = [],
        armyCircles = [],
        showShadows = 1

    camera.rotation.order = 'YXZ'
    camera.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 4
    camera.rotation.x = Math.atan(-1 / Math.sqrt(2))
    camera.position.set(0, 52, 0)
    camera.scale.addScalar(1)

    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    if (showShadows) {
        renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true
        renderer.shadowMapSoft = false
    }

    pointLight.position.set(-100000, 100000, 100000);
    scene.add(pointLight)

    theLight.position.set(1500, 1000, 1000)
    if (showShadows) {
        theLight.castShadow = true
        theLight.shadowDarkness = 0.3
        theLight.shadowMapWidth = 8192
        theLight.shadowMapHeight = 8192
    }
    scene.add(theLight);

    this.getScene = function () {
        return scene
    }
    this.getCamera = function () {
        return camera
    }
    this.getRenderer = function () {
        return renderer
    }
    this.addPathCircle = function (x, y) {
        var radius = 2,
            segments = 64,
            material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff}),
            geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, segments)

        geometry.vertices.shift()
        var circle = new THREE.Line(geometry, material)
        circle.position.set(x * 4 - 216, 0.1, y * 4 - 311)
        circle.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2

        scene.add(circle)
        circles.push(circle)
    }
    this.addArmyCircle = function (x, y) {
        var radius = 2,
            segments = 64,
            material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff}),
            geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, segments)

        geometry.vertices.shift()
        var circle = new THREE.Line(geometry, material)
        circle.position.set(x * 4 - 216, 1, y * 4 - 311)
        circle.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2

        scene.add(circle)
        armyCircles.push(circle)
    }
    this.clearPathCircles = function () {
        for (var i in circles) {
            scene.remove(circles[i])
        }
        circles = []
    }
    this.clearArmyCircles = function () {
        for (var i in armyCircles) {
            scene.remove(armyCircles[i])
        }
        armyCircles = []
    }

    var initRuin = function () {
        ruin.scale = 3
        ruinModel = loader.parse(ruin)
    }
    this.addRuin = function (x, y, color) {
        var ruinMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: color})
        ruinMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(ruinModel.geometry, ruinMaterial)
        mesh.position.set(x * 4 - 216, 0, y * 4 - 311)

        if (showShadows) {
            mesh.castShadow = true
            mesh.receiveShadow = true
        }
        scene.add(mesh)

        return mesh.id
    }

    var initTower = function () {
        tower.scale = 1.5
        towerModel = loader.parse(tower)
        flagModel = loader.parse(flag)
    }
    this.addTower = function (x, y, color) {
        var towerMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: '#6B6B6B'})
        towerMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(towerModel.geometry, towerMaterial)
        mesh.position.set(x * 4 - 216, 0, y * 4 - 311)

        if (showShadows) {
            mesh.castShadow = true
            mesh.receiveShadow = true
        }
        scene.add(mesh)

        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: color})
        material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
        var flagMesh = new THREE.Mesh(flagModel.geometry, material)
        mesh.add(flagMesh)

        return mesh
    }

    var initCastle = function () {
            castle_1.scale = 2.3
            castle_2.scale = 2.3
            castle_3.scale = 2.3
            castle_4.scale = 2.3
            castleModel_1 = loader.parse(castle_1)
            castleModel_2 = loader.parse(castle_2)
            castleModel_3 = loader.parse(castle_3)
            castleModel_4 = loader.parse(castle_4)
            flag.scale = 0.3
            flagModel = loader.parse(flag)
        },
        getCastleModel = function (defense) {
            switch (defense) {
                case 2:
                    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: '#65402C'})
                    material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
                    return new THREE.Mesh(castleModel_2.geometry, material)
                case 3:
                    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: '#0054C4'})
                    material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
                    return new THREE.Mesh(castleModel_3.geometry, material)
                case 4:
                    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: '#6B6B6B'})
                    material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
                    return new THREE.Mesh(castleModel_4.geometry, material)
            }
        },
        updateCastleModel = function (mesh, defense) {
            for (var i = 2; i <= defense; i++) {
                var m = getCastleModel(i)

                if (showShadows) {
                    m.castShadow = true
                    m.receiveShadow = true
                }
                mesh.add(m)
            }
        }


    this.addCastle = function (x, y, color, defense) {
        var castleMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: '#3B3028'})
        castleMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(castleModel_1.geometry, castleMaterial)
        mesh.position.set(x * 4 - 214, 0, y * 4 - 308)

        if (showShadows) {
            mesh.castShadow = true
            mesh.receiveShadow = true
        }
        scene.add(mesh)

        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: color})
        material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
        var flag = new THREE.Mesh(flagModel.geometry, material)
        mesh.add(flag)

        updateCastleModel(mesh, defense)
        return mesh
    }
    this.castleChangeDefense = function (mesh, defense) {
        mesh.children.splice(1, 3)
        updateCastleModel(mesh, defense)
    }

    var initArmy = function () {
        var armyModels = {
            'untitled': untitled,
            'archers': archers,
            'hero': hero,
            'light_infantry': light_infantry,
            'heavy_infantry': heavy_infantry,
            'giants': giants,
            'dwarves': dwarves,
            'griffins': griffins,
            'dragon': dragon,
            'cavalry': cavalry,
            'navy': navy,
            'wolves': wolves
        }
        for (var i in armyModels) {
            armyModels[i].scale = 6
            window[i + 'Model'] = loader.parse(armyModels[i])
        }

        flag_1.scale = 5
        flag_1Model = loader.parse(flag_1)
        flag_2.scale = 5
        flag_2Model = loader.parse(flag_2)
        flag_3.scale = 5
        flag_3Model = loader.parse(flag_3)
        flag_4.scale = 5
        flag_4Model = loader.parse(flag_4)
        flag_5.scale = 5
        flag_5Model = loader.parse(flag_5)
        flag_6.scale = 5
        flag_6Model = loader.parse(flag_6)
        flag_7.scale = 5
        flag_7Model = loader.parse(flag_7)
        flag_8.scale = 5
        flag_8Model = loader.parse(flag_8)
    }
    this.addArmy = function (x, y, color, number, modelName) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: color})
        material.side = THREE.DoubleSide

        var armyMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: color})
        armyMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide

        if (modelName + 'Model' in window) {
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(window[modelName + 'Model'].geometry, armyMaterial)
        } else {
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(untitledModel.geometry, armyMaterial)
        }

        mesh.position.set(x * 4 - 216, 0, y * 4 - 311)
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI / 4

        if (showShadows) {
            mesh.castShadow = true
            mesh.receiveShadow = true
        }
        var flagMesh = new THREE.Mesh(getFlag(number).geometry, material)
        flagMesh.position.set(-2, 0, 0)
        mesh.add(flagMesh)

        scene.add(mesh)

        return mesh
    }
    //this.armyChangeFlag = function (mesh, color, number, modelName) {
    //    mesh.children.splice(0, 1)
    //
    //    var armyMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: color})
    //    armyMaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide
    //
    //    if (modelName + 'Model' in window) {
    //        mesh.geometry = window[modelName + 'Model'].geometry
    //    } else {
    //        mesh.geometry = untitledModel.geometry
    //    }
    //
    //    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: color})
    //    material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
    //    var flagMesh = new THREE.Mesh(getFlag(number).geometry, material)
    //    flagMesh.position.set(-2, 0, 0)
    //    mesh.add(flagMesh)
    //}
    var getFlag = function (number) {
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                return flag_1Model
            case 2:
                return flag_2Model
            case 3:
                return flag_3Model
            case 4:
                return flag_4Model
            case 5:
                return flag_5Model
            case 6:
                return flag_6Model
            case 7:
                return flag_7Model
            default :
                return flag_8Model
        }
    }

    var loadGround = function () {
        var ground = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(436, 624), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('/img/maps/1.png')}));
        //var ground = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(436, 624), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00dd00}));
        ground.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2
        if (showShadows) {
            ground.receiveShadow = true
        }
        scene.add(ground)
        Picker.attach(ground)
    }

    var initFields = function () {
        tree.scale = 3
        water.scale = 1.7

        mountainModel = loader.parse(mountain)
        hillModel = loader.parse(hill)
        treeModel = loader.parse(tree)
        waterModel = loader.parse(water)

        mountainModel.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: '#808080'})
        mountainModel.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide

        hillModel.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: '#00a000'})
        hillModel.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
        //hillModel.scale = 0.7

        treeModel.material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: '#008000'})
        treeModel.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
        //treeModel.scale = 0.4

        waterModel.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0x0000ff})
        waterModel.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide
    }

    this.addMountain = function (x, y) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(mountainModel.geometry, mountainModel.material)
        mesh.position.set(x * 4 - 216, 0, y * 4 - 311)
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI * Math.random()

        if (showShadows) {
            mesh.castShadow = true
            mesh.receiveShadow = true
        }
        scene.add(mesh)

    }
    this.addHill = function (x, y) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(hillModel.geometry, hillModel.material)
        mesh.position.set(x * 4 - 216, 0, y * 4 - 311)
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI * Math.random()

        if (showShadows) {
//mesh.castShadow = true
            mesh.receiveShadow = true
        }
        scene.add(mesh)
    }
    this.addTree = function (x, y) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(treeModel.geometry, treeModel.material)
        mesh.position.set(x * 4 - 216, 0, y * 4 - 311)
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI * Math.random()

        if (showShadows) {
            mesh.castShadow = true
            mesh.receiveShadow = true
        }
        scene.add(mesh)
    }
    this.addWater = function (x, y) {
        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(waterModel.geometry, waterModel.material)
        mesh.position.set(x * 4 - 216, 0.1, y * 4 - 311)
        mesh.rotation.y = Math.PI * Math.random()

        scene.add(mesh)
    }

    this.init = function (fields) {
        initRuin()
        initTower()
        initCastle()
        initArmy()
        initFields()
        $('#game').append(renderer.domElement)
        loadGround()
        render()
    }
    var render = function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(render)
        renderer.render(scene, camera)
    }
}
```

You can find working example at http://wof.failpoint.pl

login:test

password: test11

After login you can load existing game.

Answer (score 0):

This is (in spite of all) problem with my and my friends graphic drivers. It is working fine elsewhere.